# Laravel middleware auth with external database

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, middleware

I can't use built in MySQL database in Laravel 8, i have to authenticate with an external ORACLE database.

I have a LoginController with this code:

```
$oracle = new OracleController();
$conn = $oracle->trconnect();

$sql = "select USERNAME, USERID from OFUSERS where USERNAME = '$fnev'";
$result = $oracle->trlekerdez($conn, $sql);
oci_close($conn);
if ($result) {
    request()->session()->regenerate();
    return redirect()->route('main')->with('success', 'Logged in successfully!');
} else {
    return redirect()->route('login')->with('username', $fnev)->withErrors(['doflogin' => 'User not found!']);
}
```

This works fine, but when i use this route with **->middleware('auth')**, i can't reach main route:

`Route::get('/main', [DofController::class, 'main'])->middleware('auth')->name('main');`

Can i use middleware('auth')? If not, than what is the solution? How can i authenticate a user with Oracle?

Comment: would it not make more sense to create this oracle connection in config/database.php and set it as the default connection?

Answer (score -1):

Using Laravel's built-in authentication middleware (auth) with an external Oracle database for authentication isn't straightforward because Laravel's authentication system is primarily designed to work with the Eloquent ORM and its built-in authentication methods. However, you can create a custom middleware to handle authentication with your Oracle database.

Here's how you can approach this:

Create Custom Middleware: Create a custom middleware that handles authentication against your Oracle database.

Middleware Logic: Inside the middleware, implement the logic to authenticate users against your Oracle database.

Apply Middleware: Apply your custom middleware to routes that require authentication instead of using the built-in auth middleware.

Here's a basic example of how you might implement this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Services\OracleService; // Assuming you have a service to interact with Oracle

class OracleAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    protected $oracleService;

    public function __construct(OracleService $oracleService)
    {
        $this->oracleService = $oracleService;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Check if user is authenticated against Oracle
        if ($this->oracleService->authenticate($request->input('username'), $request->input('password'))) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        // If not authenticated, redirect back to login
        return redirect()->route('login')->withErrors(['doflogin' => 'User not found!']);
    }
}
```

In this example, OracleService is a placeholder for a service class where you implement the logic to authenticate users against your Oracle database. You should replace it with your actual implementation.

Then, apply this middleware to your routes:

```
Route::middleware('oracle.auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/main', [DofController::class, 'main'])->name('main');
});
```

Make sure to bind your OracleService in the service container, so Laravel can inject it into your middleware.

```
$this->app->singleton(OracleService::class, function ($app) {
    return new OracleService(/* inject any dependencies here */);
});
```

With this setup, requests to /main will be intercepted by your custom middleware, which will handle authentication against your Oracle database. If the user is authenticated, the request will proceed to the main controller method; otherwise, the user will be redirected back to the login page.